# Bash file descriptor redirection mystery

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection, file-descriptors

This is a mystery encountered at work today.  Note that this behavior seems to be specific to a binary that I do not know the contents of, but any ideas as to how this phenomenon could occur would be welcome.  It's not of much consequence whether or not this mystery is solved, but it would be gratifying to know what could cause this.  Basically, it looks like this:

With either of these two commands, `mystderr` contains the output that `mybinary` printed to stderr (desired behavior):

```
$ ./mybinary 3>&1 1>mystdout 2>&3 3>&- | cat > mystderr
$ ./mybinary 3>&1 1>mystdout 2>&3 3>&- | while read line; do echo "$line"; done | grep -P ".*"; done > mystderr
```

With either of these two commands, `mystderr` contains nothing, `strace` shows that perl/grep get the input but do not write to stdout:

```
$ ./mybinary 3>&1 1>mystdout 2>&3 3>&- | perl -pe '/.*/p' > mystderr
$ ./mybinary 3>&1 1>mystdout 2>&3 3>&- | grep -P ".*" > mystderr
```

Why does `cat` know what to do, but `grep` doesn't?  Why does just feeding the lines through a bash loop cause `grep` to figure out what to do?